# how to perform click and gettext operation for every click operation we performed

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have a multiple class having same attribute value i want to perform click operation for these class and this will open another panel where i want to click and gettext 
basically i performed click operation in a loop and now i need to add for every click operation i need to extract text

For every click operation performed on `"class = coral-Icon coral-Icon--chevronRight coral-Icon--sizeXS u-coral-pullRight"`, I need to perform click operation on `"class = opt-tt-1 cq-TestCase-flag coral-Icon coral-Icon--branchCircle "` and get text from `"testrunner-results-container"`

Code trials:

```
driver.findElements(webdriver.By.className("coral-Icon coral-Icon--chevronRight coral-Icon--sizeXS u-coral-pullRight")).then((elements) => {
    for(n=0; n <elements.length; n++) {
        elements[n].click();

        driver.findElements(webdriver.By.className("opt-tt-1 cq-TestCase-flag coral-Icon coral-Icon--branchCircle ")).then( function(elements1) {
            promise.map(elements1, function (el3) {
                 el3.click();

                driver.findElements(webdriver.By.className("testrunner-results-container")).then(function (elements2) {
                    promise.map(elements2, function (el4){
                        var el = el.getText();
                        console.log(el)
                   })
                })
            })
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: for every click operation performed on "class = coral-Icon coral-Icon--chevronRight coral-Icon--sizeXS u-coral-pullRight"  i need to perform click operation on "class = opt-tt-1 cq-TestCase-flag coral-Icon coral-Icon--branchCircle " and get text from "testrunner-results-container"

Comment: Can you try to explain the problem that you're having with the code above? I can make some guesses, but a lot more info is needed to have an answer for sure. What is not happening that you expect to happen?

Comment: i want my code to work like this i have 20 elements having same class = coral-Icon coral-Icon--chevronRight coral-Icon--sizeXS u-coral-pullRight  i have used for loop to find each element and try to click. once for each element is clicked then a sub pannel will open until now my code is working fine . Once the subpannel is opened where i have a button whith class name=opt-tt-1 cq-TestCase-flag coral-Icon coral-Icon--branchCircle   once i click on it it will open my results having class name = testrunner-results-container where i need to getText().

Comment: when i tried to run the test case then it is returning result is undeffined and when i tried to add wait time after first click on class   coral-Icon coral-Icon--chevronRight coral-Icon--sizeXS u-coral-pullRight then it is going next click and skipping gettext()

Comment: Are you able to post ant html to help with troubleshooting? If I were to take a guess at this point, it is probably that you aren't looking at the children properly. There might also be a much easier way to get the information that you want from the page.